# Clearing LAST_INSERT_ID() before inserting to tell if what's returned is from my insert

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, last-insert-id

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the most recent id generated for the current connection by an auto increment column, but how do I tell if that value is from the last insert and not from a previous insert on the same connection?

Suppose I am using a connection from a pool, which may have inserted a row before I got the connection, and I execute an conditional insert:

```
insert into mytable (colA)
select 'foo' from bar
where <some condition>;
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I have no way of knowing if the value returned is from my insert.

One way I thought of is:

```
@previousId := LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into mytable (colA)
select 'foo' from bar
where <some condition>;
select if(LAST_INSERT_ID() != @previousId, LAST_INSERT_ID(), null);
```

Is there a way to "clear" the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` value, so I know it's a fresh value caused by my SQL if a non-zero value is returned?

Comment: This is a partially-solved problem. Could you post the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What's wrong with using `row_count`, as Digital Chris suggested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) to determine if your conditional insert attempt was successful, and then return `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or a default value based on that:

```
select IF(ROW_COUNT() > 0, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 0);
```

Answer (score 13):

I agree with [@Digital Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20705405), that you should not be determining whether an insertion succeeded or failed via inspection of the value returned by [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id): there are more direct routes, such as the affected row count.  Nevertheless, there might still be some requirement to obtain a "clean" value from [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Of course, one problem with your proposed solution (of comparing against the pre-insertion value) is that it might happen that the insertion was successful *and* that its assigned auto-incremented value is coincidentally the same as that of the previous insertion (presumably on another table).  The comparison could therefore lead to an assumption that the insertion failed, whereas it had in fact succeeded.

I recommend that, if at all possible, you avoid using the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) SQL function in preference for the [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html) API call (via your driver).  As explained under the documentation for the latter:

> [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html) returns `0` if the previous statement does not use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. If you need to save the value for later, be sure to call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html) immediately after the statement that generates the value.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The reason for the differences between [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html) is that [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is made easy to use in scripts while [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html) tries to provide more exact information about what happens to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

In any event, as documented under [`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> If ***`expr`*** is given as an argument to [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), the value of the argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next value to be returned by [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Therefore, before performing your [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html), you could reset with:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(NULL);
```

This also ought to reset the value returned by [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html), although the documentation suggests the call to [`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) must take place within an [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) or [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) statement—may require testing to verify.  In any event, it ought to be pretty trivial to create such a no-op statement if so required:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) SELECT NULL WHERE LAST_INSERT_ID(NULL);
```

It may be worth noting that one can also set the [`identity`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_identity) and [`last_insert_id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_last_insert_id) system variables (however these only affect the value returned by [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and not by [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-insert-id.html)):

```
SET @@last_insert_id := NULL;
```

Answer (score 9):

You speculate that you might get the previous `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, but practically, I don't see where this case would happen. If you're doing a conditional insert, you would HAVE to check whether it was successful before taking next steps. For example, you would always use `ROW_COUNT()` to check inserted/updated records. Pseudo-code:

```
insert into mytable (colA)
select 'foo' from bar
where <some condition>;

IF ROW_COUNT() > 0
    select LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -- ...use selected last_insert_id for other updates/inserts...
END IF;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is [full](http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/03ak30pqa6/changing-last-insert-id-auto-increment) of [gotchas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21181/is-mysqls-last-insert-id-function-guaranteed-to-be-correct), I use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to record the ID in a log table and in a manner consistent with the problem I'm trying to solve.

In your scenario, since the insert is conditional, use a unqiue identifier to "tag" the insert, then check for the presence of that tag in the insert log.  If the identifying tag is present, your insert occurred and you have the inserted ID.  If the identifying tag is not present, no insert occurred.

**Reference Implementation**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_AI AFTER INSERT ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable_InsertLog (myTableId, ident) VALUES (NEW.myTableId, COALESCE(@tag, CONNECTION_ID()));
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE MyTable_InsertLog (
    myTableId BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES MyTable (myTableId),
    tag CHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

**Example Usage**

```
SET @tag=MD5('A');
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT NULL,colA FROM Foo WHERE colA='whatever';
SELECT myTableId FROM MyTable_InsertLog WHERE tag=@tag;
DELETE FROM MyTable_InsertLog WHERE tag=@tag;
```

If the insert succeeds, you will get rows from the select -- and those rows will have your ID.  No rows, no insert.  Either way, delete results from the insert log so that you can reuse that tag in subsequent calls.

Comment: after insert trigger wouldn't help. my app code needs the id of the row just added, but only if it *was* added. i need to be able to distinguish that the last insert id returned from the function is from the sql i just executed

Comment: @Bohemian: Sure you can, if I'm understanding your use case correctly.  See my edit for working example.

Answer (score 2):

The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function has a rather narrow scope of application: as MySQL does not support SQL `SEQUENCE`s, this is used to create a transaction that `INSERT`s data consistently into multiple tables, if one references the surrogate key from the other table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, value INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE bar (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, fooref INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO foo(value) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO bar(fooref) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

If you really want to use this in a conditional insert, you need to make the second `INSERT` conditional as well by joining the inserted values against the `SELECT` from the first `INSERT` and subsequently throwing away the extra columns (so that the second `INSERT` also has zero or one row).

I'd advise against that, though. The conditional insert in this manner is already somewhat brittle, and building on top of it will not add stability to your application.

Comment: No good. There is no second insert. The last insert id is used outside the database by the app code. Besides, this does't answer the question either.

Comment: The answer is "you're not expected to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in this way." That is why I commented asking for a description of the original problem.

Comment: I want to get the last inserted id from the sql into my application, but my sql does a conditional insert, so I need to be able to distinguish between the last inserted id coming from my insert or the previous insert for the connection I'm using. If it's not from my insert (attempt), I want it to be zero or null.

Comment: That is not a supported use case. Even if you find a solution that works, it may just break at any time in the future, and you get to keep the pieces.